# Prevent windbg from context switching when stepping into assembly instructions

Tags: windows, debugging, windbg, breakpoint

When I'm using Windbg (in kernel mode) to step into assembly, I would encounter context switching once in a while - which is annoying.

So, for example, I placed a breakpoint for a process - let's call it `A.exe` using `bp /1 /p <EPROCESS OF A> nt!NtDeviceIoControlFile`. `A` runs, hits the breakpoint and as I am stepping into the assembly, sometimes, the context switches - so the current process, instead of `A`, becomes `B`.

Is there anyway to prevent this from happening?

Comment: how are you stepping using t or p  p allows free execution try to stick to t   or  use a process specific bp one time bp on next instruction prior to p

Comment: @blabb what do u mean? I couldnt catch you

Comment: @Kyoma: how do you "step into assembly"? what exact command/hotkey are you using?

Comment: @IgorSkochinsky F11